# rock paper scissor program in c++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner, I am not able to find what I am doing wrong in this program of rock paper scissors. Can someone help please. below is my code:

I have created two function one userchoice() which accept input from the user and return an corresponding string. Second is compchoice(), random number is generated from 1 to 3 and and corresponding string is returned, then I call the fucntions and save the value in variable which I compare in a while loop to see if the user input matches with computers.

```
using namespace std;

string compchoice();
string userchoice();
int main() {
   //cout<<"computer picks a choice here"<<compchoice()<<endl;
   //cout<<"pick your choice "<<userchoice()<<endl;
   string comp, user;
   comp = compchoice();
   user = userchoice();
   while (userchoice() != compchoice()) {
      if (userchoice() != compchoice()) {
         cout << " go again \n\t";
         comp = compchoice();
         user = userchoice();
      } else {
         cout << "congratulations\t computer choice was " << comp <<
                 " user choice is " << user;
         //comp = compchoice();
         //user = userchoice();
      }
   }
}
string compchoice() {
   srand(time(0));
   int ch;
   string choiceStr;
   ch = rand() % 3 + 1;
   switch (ch) {
      case 1:
         choiceStr = "rock";
         break;
      case 2:
         choiceStr = "paper";
         break;
      case 3:
         choiceStr = "scissors";
         break;
      default:
         cout << "computer menu.... existing";
         //break;
   }
   return choiceStr;
}
string userchoice() {
   string choiceStr;
   int choice;
   cout << " 1. rock \n";
   cout << " 2. paper \n";
   cout << " 3. scissors \n";
   cout << " user menu make selection : \n";
   cin >> choice;
   cout << endl;
   switch (choice) {
      case 1:
         choiceStr = "rock";
         break;
      case 2:
         choiceStr = "paper";
         break;
      case 3:
         choiceStr = "scissors";
         break;
      default:
         choiceStr = "enter only 1, 2, or 3";
         //break;
   }
   return choiceStr;
}
```

Comment: There are a zillion `rock paper scissor` questions on SO (I guess it must be a common homework problem). Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: Where are your `#include`s?  And what problems are you having, input? output?

Comment: A lot of code that may work. Nice. And now what?

Answer (score 1):

Your program can't be compiled because you missed to add these includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
```

*Edit*:
You should also avoid using the whole `namespace std`. That's too broad. Use specific `using`s instead:

```
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```